# User-defined CLR data types in Windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have created user defined data types in my project.  Now I am going to deploy my project on Windwos Azure.

I have defined user defined CLR data types in my sql server 2008 database. As much as I have read about user-defined CLR data types, these are not supported in Windows Azure SQL Database.

Is there any alternative for databases with user-defined CLR datatypes when migrating to Windows Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Are you porting your SQL Server 2008 database to a Windows Azure SQL database?

Comment: User-defined *CLR* datatypes are what are not supported in a Windows Azure SQL database.  Is your user-defined type a *CLR* type?

Comment: Yes these are CLR types

Comment: Ah - then you do have a problem on your hands. As far as I know, there is currently no way to do what you need to do.

Comment: @STLDeveloper is there any alternate of user defined data types in sql azure?

Comment: Not at this point in time.  Perhaps this will be allowed in the future.  How complex is your database?  Does it have many tables?  Can you translate it into standard SQL Server data types?  I think that this is your only alternative if you *must* move it to a Windows Azure SQL database.

Comment: If you require this flexibility - you could always use an **Azure VM** to host **SQL Server** (*IaaS*). You would have to manage the OS and DB software updates yourself though. [Azure SQL Server VMs can scale and support high availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj870962.aspx) - it's just a lot more work (*and probably cost*) if you require it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User-defined CLR data types are not supported on Windows Azure Database. Relevant documentation:

> Windows Azure SQL Database does not support user-defined common language runtime (CLR) data types.

Source: [Data Types (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336233.aspx).

> The following features that were new to SQL Server 2008 are not supported by Windows Azure SQL Database: (...) Extension of spatial types and methods through Common Language Runtime (CLR)
>   The following features that were new to SQL Server 2005 are not supported by Windows Azure SQL Database: (...) Common Language Runtime (CLR) and CLR User-Defined Types

Source: [SQL Server Feature Limitations (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx).

Alternatives:

1) Change the application to use only data types supported by Windows Azure SQL Database. Downside: requires code and database changes. Upside: hosted, highly available service.

2) Use an on-premises or third-party SQL Server. Downside: you have to host SQL Server yourself or pay someone to host it; latency may be an issue; availability and management is your concern. Upside: full SQL Server compatibility.

3) Host [SQL Server in Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/jj823132.aspx) using VM images published by Microsoft. Downside: management is your concern; high availability requires [additional configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj870962.aspx). Upside: full SQL Server compatibility; low latency; highly available infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

CLR is now supported on SQL Azure databases.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/401015-support-clr-stored-procedures

I haven't created an assembly yet, since that's the tricky part.

It's not clear if this is only for SAFE mode.

Comment: Microsoft has pulled the rug out from everyone's feet after having added that feature:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/breaking-news-literally-sql-clr-support-removed-azure-sql-db/

Comment: I never trusted CLR on Azure so never implemented it. Thanks for making that official.

Comment: Yeah, and with a 7 day warning period to boot. A real kick in the nuts.